# Reset MVC form with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, forms, reset

How do I reset a form?

i.e. Clear values of all fields and remove ValidationSummary error messages validation-summary-errors with jquery.

I use the below code but it does not work:

```
    var validator = $("#myform").validate();
    validator.resetForm();
```

I'm using asp.net MVC3 and the jquery scripts are include in my page.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: @Ken: Good point, sorry for not being more verbose.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
$('.field-validation-error')
    .removeClass('field-validation-error')
    .addClass('field-validation-valid');

$('.input-validation-error')
    .removeClass('input-validation-error')
    .addClass('valid');
```

Comment: I was expecting `resetForm()` to do this.. I was wrong. Thank you

Comment: I found this to work for me $('.field-validation-error').remove();

Answer (score 54):

I wrote a quick jQuery extension to handle this issue when I encountered it which:

- Clears field level validation errors
- Clears/hides validation summary
- **Resets jQuery Validate's internal error list**

It can be called from an element $(selected) within the form or on the form its self.

Here is a calling example (the input is within a form):

```
<input onclick="$(this).resetValidation()" type="reset" value="Reset" />
```

Here is the jQuery plugin code:

```
(function ($) {

    //re-set all client validation given a jQuery selected form or child
    $.fn.resetValidation = function () {

        var $form = this.closest('form');

        //reset jQuery Validate's internals
        $form.validate().resetForm();

        //reset unobtrusive validation summary, if it exists
        $form.find("[data-valmsg-summary=true]")
            .removeClass("validation-summary-errors")
            .addClass("validation-summary-valid")
            .find("ul").empty();

        //reset unobtrusive field level, if it exists
        $form.find("[data-valmsg-replace]")
            .removeClass("field-validation-error")
            .addClass("field-validation-valid")
            .empty();

        return $form;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Hopefully this helped! You can read more about it and see some other examples on my blog post here as well:

http://www.johnculviner.com/post/2011/11/16/ClearReset-MVC-3-Form-and-Unobtrusive-jQuery-Client-Validation.aspx

Comment: Haha sweet! Glad its still useful :)

Comment: Tried four suggestions. This was the one that worked.

Comment: @JohnCulviner you just saved my precious time..thanks

Comment: It seems there also should be something like `$form.find(".input-validation-error").removeClass("input-validation-error");`

Comment: Spent hours trying different suggestions on SO and elsewhere but to no avail until I found this one! Great answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

you could use native solution (validate 1.9.0 + unobtrusive)

```
var $form = $(this).closest('form');

// reset errors with unobtrusive
$form.trigger('reset.unobtrusiveValidation');

// reset inputs
var validator = $form.validate(); // get saved validator
//validator.settings.ignore = ''; // if form hided (closed ui dialogs, etc)
validator.resetForm();
```

Comment: You don't need to do the resetForm at the end. The triggered event does it internally.

Comment: This works, but the validation summary remains invisible on subsequent form submits.

Answer (score 4):

To follow up from Darin Dimitrov's message the following will also clear the validation summary...

```
$(".validation-summary-errors")
        .removeClass("validation-summary-errors")
        .addClass("validation-summary-valid");
```

Answer (score 1):

To completement Darin and Kennifer answer, I put everything together and added a last part to reenable lazy validation

```
        //Reset validation message
        $('.field-validation-error')
        .removeClass('field-validation-error')
        .addClass('field-validation-valid');

        //Reset input, select and textarea style
        $('.input-validation-error')
        .removeClass('input-validation-error')
        .addClass('valid');

        //Reset validation summary
        $(".validation-summary-errors")
        .removeClass("validation-summary-errors")
        .addClass("validation-summary-valid");

        //To reenable lazy validation (no validation until you submit the form)
        $('form').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
        $('form').removeData('validator');
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses `find` to search first for the `container` then the child `list`. If the list is empty the class `validation-summary-valid` is added to the container and `validation-summary-errors` removed.

```
var container = $('form').find('[data-valmsg-summary="true"]');
var list = container.find('ul');

if (list && list.length) {
    list.empty();
    container.addClass('validation-summary-valid').removeClass('validation-summary-errors');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-clear-form/

Happy coding