# Button Cancel causes validation...I dont want validation on Cancel Button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

So I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363624/disable-client-side-validation-in-mvc-3-cancel-submit-button) but it is not helping at all, I tried to do the same and is not working.

I have this button:

```
<button id="btnCancel" type="button" class="cancel" name="btnCancel" value="Cancel" onclick="onCancel()">Cancel</button>
```

Which cleans my form, and causes validation (which I want to remove)

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
OnCancel function:

```
function onCancel()
{
    $('#ddlConfigTypeName').val("")
    $('#ddlThreshold').val("")
    $('#ddlValueTypeName').val("")
    $('#txtbLocation').val("")
    $('#txtbLimit').val("")
    $('#QueueMonitorConfigurationsID').val(-1)
    $("#valSummary").empty();
}
```

Comment: Don't you need `type="button"` on that?

Comment: TRUE. But I want to hide the validation messages that are shown, so if I click the submit button and there are validation errors, and then I press cancel, I want to erase them

Comment: Have you tried adding it to it? What does 'onCancel()' look like?

Comment: Just added the code. Adding what?

Comment: Yes I did, and is not validating now but still not achieving that

Comment: `not achieving that`, not achieving what? If it is no longer validating, doesn't that answer your question? The problem now lies in the clearing of your form fields validation errors. You will probably want to remove the validation class (.input-validation-error) that the default validation adds via your `onCancel()` method. e.g. `$('#ddlConfigTypeName').removeClass('.input-validation-error');`

Comment: I'm showing the validation messages with a validation summary, not a validation message for each field.
And yes the question is answered, I'm just wondering how to do the rest

Comment: If you're using the validation summary then you can toggle this in jquery too `$('div.validation-summary-errors').attr('display', 'none');` or just `$('div.validation-summary-errors').toggle();`

Comment: but then if I click `cancel` again, it will toggle again the errors

Comment: Dont use .toggle() then, use the method before that. Explore a little, this is an easy problem to solve on your own

Comment: Well, it's not working, it does nothing. I debugged and no script errors, and the code is executed, but nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

```
    $('form').find("[data-valmsg-summary=true]")
         .removeClass("validation-summary-errors")
         .addClass("validation-summary-valid")
         .find("ul").empty();
```

Somehow, only this solution I found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457393/reset-mvc-form-with-jquery) worked for me. It's not even the correct answer marked in that post.